# How can make checkbox select and multiple selection with Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

> my code is without button that make select all

**View class**

```
GetBuilder<ProductController>(
                              
                              builder: (controller) {
                                
                              
                              return
                            
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              child: Transform.scale(
                                scale: 1.2,
                                child:  Checkbox(
                                  activeColor: MyThemes.yellow,
                                  shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
                                  ),
                                  splashRadius: 18.8,
                                  value: controller.items[index]["check"],
                                   onChanged:((value) {
                                    controller.CheckBrand(index, value);
                                  } 
                                )),
                              ),
                            );}),
```

**controller class**

```
    RxList<Map<String,dynamic>> items = [{"one": "Item1", "check": false}, 
  {"one": "Item2", "check": false}, {"one": "Item3", "check": false}].obs;



CheckBrand(index, ischeck){   items[index]["check"]=ischeck;   update(); }
```

> I want to ask is there another way to make checkbox selection and how can I make select all button for this items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate over elements to check them all at once, you can use this method:

```
void checkAll({bool newValue = true}) {
 items.value.forEach((element) {
  element["check"] = newValue;
 });

update();
}
```

I will add also a method that uncheck all at once:

```
void unCheckAll() { 
 checkAll(newValue: false);
}
```

now from your view, just call it like this:

```
controller.checkAll(); // will check all check boxes
controller.unCheckAll(); // will uncheck all check boxes
```

Comment: I want to ask y you is there another way to make checkbox selection with getx ?